Azure DevOps task "Azure Functions Deploy" doesn't create app setting with provided value - escape issue \r\n
Issue
We have a function app in Azure, and from Azure DevOps, through a classic release pipeline, we deploy the function and app settings.
One of those app settings has a value "abc\r\ndef\r\nghi\r\n..."
However, when we deploy this app setting from DevOps, the value in Azure portal becomes
"abc\\r\\ndef\\r\\nghi\\r\\n..."
Does anyone know why, and how to avoid this additional \ being added please?
Here's an overview of the task group tasks:

What I noticed
In the Azure portal UI, the value of the app setting shows as it was provided in DevOps. Thus, with single \ where needed.
However, in the underlying json, via Advanced Edit on the app settings, I see that the actual (real/used) value has double \ characters.
What I tried

I tried using ` instead of \. This didn't help.
If I provide the correct value, with single \ via Advanced Edit, the sftp connection that I'm trying to make works fine. However, we don't want to do this manually.

Edit after key vault integration
I noticed that when I use (backtick)n instead of \r\n I can force PowerShell to create new lines. With \r\n this doesn't work.

However, when I store the private key in the key vault, containing `n for new lines, this doesn't work via the function.

\n in the key vault secret value also does not work.
PS. I know I should not be outputting the private key value, but I'm doing this now for testing purposes only.

Are you sure that the variable being used in the App Settings section of the task has the right value? Where is this value coming from?

Yes Rui, when I provide the value of the private key app setting with \r\n via the Advanced edit, the connection works fine.

I also tried using 
 instead of \r\n, but no luck...

I probably didn't explain myself properly - I meant checking if the variable has the right value without editing the pipeline via the Advance Edit. For example, try adding a dummy task to print the value, for testing purposes only.

The variable is marked as secret, since it contains a private key for sftp. I can't output that in DevOps logs. But I'm sure it has the right value, I didn't put it in there with double slashes.

Is that secret stored in an Azure Key Vault? Have you considered using a Key Vault reference, as opposed to use the value directly in the app settings? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#source-app-settings-from-key-vault

I have not tried that yet, but that may be a good solution. I'll try it and post back.

Keep in mind that you need to grant your app access to a keyvault: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#grant-your-app-access-to-a-key-vault

Tried and failed. The key vault reference resolves OK. The value of the secret is as I would put it in the 'Advanced edit' on the app settings overview. The result is "Private key is invalid". Not sure if it could have anything to do with the function PowerShell looking like this $keystring = $env:sftpprivatekey?

After implementing the key vault structure as suggested by Rui Jarimba, I had to update the PowerShell code of the function just a little to make this work.
Basically, the function retrieves the value of the secret from the key vault as plain text. To work around it I added a 'replace'.
Example where \n is used in the key vault secret value:
$keystring = $env:sftpprivatekey 
$privatekey = $keystring.Replace('\n', "`n") # keystring is retrieved from key vault as plain text, \n is treated as literal character. A 'replace' helps to enforce the escape sequence for newline character.

The sFTP connection could then be made via:
$SFTPSession  = New-SFTPSession  -Computer $computer -Credential $credential -Port $port -KeyString $privatekey -AcceptKey:$true -Verbose


You may use Azure Keyvault to store multiline settings. Then create a reference from the setting:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)

Additionally, you may use PowerShell to set the variable:
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name $functionName -ResourceGroupName $functionAppResGroup -AppSetting @{$appsettingname = "true`nfalse"} -Force

The result:


I will be using key vault to store the value indeed. I will not be using the additional PowerShell to set the value. Using an additional PowerShell task also feels wrong since I'm using the DevOps task to deploy the function which should be able to set the value of app settings also. I'll only use that approach if nothing else works.
